# Find the list of posts with tags by id tag ,Spring Data Jpa Bidirectional

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, many-to-many

Choose all posts with tags that include tag by id and use DTO to select some field.

The title of the tag with id 1 is JAVA33333333, I want this output above
tag/1 GET

```
{
   "id":1,
   "title":"meu camarada a gente filips",
   "createdAt":"17-06-2021",
   "slug":"meu-camarada-a-gente-filips",
   "summary":"Criar conteúdo para blogs  ",
   "tags":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "title":"JAVA33333333"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "title":"python33333333"
      }
   ]
},
{
   "id":2,
   "title":"LULA LIVRE",
   "slug":"lula-ladrao",
   "summary":"Criar conteúdo para blogs ",
   "tags":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "title":"JAVA33333333"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "title":"python33333333"
      }
   ]
},
{
   "id":3,
   "title":"LULA LIVRE pcsharp",
   "slug":"lula-ladrao-pcsharp",
   "summary":"Criar conteúdo suficiente",
   "tags":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "title":"JAVA33333333"
      }
   ]
}
```

My projection and query return error

> "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",

```
public interface PostResponseProjection {
    Long getId();
    String getTitle();
    LocalDateTime getCreatedAt();
    String getSlug();
    String getSummary();
    List<TagProjectionResponse> getTags();
}
public interface TagProjectionResponse {
    Long getId();
    String getTitle();
}

@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag, Long> {
 
  @Query("SELECT post.id as id "+
        ",post.title as title "+            
        ",post.createdAt as createdAt"+
        ",post.slug as slug"+
        ",post.summary as summary"+
        ",post.tags as tags "+
        "FROM Tag tag INNER JOIN tag.posts post WHERE tag.id=:tagId")
  Set<PostResponseProjection> findAllPostWthByTagId(@Param("tagId") Long id);
}
```

Post

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Post {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;   
    private String title;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String body;
    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING,pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate createdAt = LocalDate.now();
    private String slug;
    private PublishedStatus status;
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String summary;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    },fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="post_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
    )
    @JsonProperty("tags")
     @JsonIgnoreProperties("posts")    
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Tag

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags",fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Edit: If you use this query below, you will get another error.

```
@Query("SELECT tag.posts FROM Tag tag INNER JOIN tag.posts post WHERE tag.id=:tagId")
```

> Requested tuple value [index=0,
> realType=com.microservices.post.model.Post] cannot be assigned to
> requested type [java.util.Set]; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested tuple value [index=0,
> realType=com.microservices.post.model.Post] cannot be assigned to
> requested type [java.util.Set]",

Edit 2: If using query Select Post in PostRepository works fine, but hibernate makes 6 select this is too big.

```
@Query("SELECT post FROM Post post JOIN post.tags as tags where tags.id= :tagId")
 Set<PostResponseProjection> findAllPostByTagsId(@Param("tagId") Long id);
```

Comment: looks like you need to use projection or tuples if you want to specify the result set elements in the query.

Comment: PostResponseProjection is a projection, I upadte this thread with another error, ```Post cannot be assigned to requested type [java.util.Set```

Comment: True, you cannot have collections in the projection with JPA.

Comment: @K.Nicholas If using query Select Post in PostRepository works fine, but hibernate makes 6 select this is too big.

Comment: Yea, if you want a single query you need `join fetch`. You are supposed to use `EntityGraphs` to do this type of query in JPA, but a query should work also. I think an EntityGraph will know to do a join fetch but it's been awhile since I played around with this.